# Use wchar_t *buff with variable

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I use theres lines for change the wallpaper of Windows

```c
    const wchar_t *path = L"C:\\Users\\Prince 2 lu\\Desktop\\SDL\\bin\\image\\wallpaper.png";
    SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (void *)path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

this code here ^ work completly
but the code

```c
SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "C:\\Users\\Prince 2 lu\\Desktop\\SDL\\bin\\image\\wallpaper.png", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

or

```c
char *buff = "C:\\Users\\Prince 2 lu\\Desktop\\SDL\\bin\\image\\wallpaper.png";
SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, buff, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

Doesn't work, I doesn't have idea why, if anybody knows why...
But i would like use a variable to define path
(because the path file can change for the users)
i want define path in a char* (the file path of the wallpaper)
the code
(if buff is simply a char pointer)
`char *buff = file.path;`

```c
wchar_t *path = buff;
```

Doesn't work, someone have a solution?

---

Compiler: MingGW64

OS: Windows 10 B4 bits

Comment: What *is* `buff`? What do you need it for? *How* doesn't it work?

Comment: By the way, it could be good to know that arrays (assuming `buff` is an array) automatically decay to pointers to their first element. If `buff` is an array of `wchar_t`, then you don't need `path` but can use `buff` directly in the call to `SystemParametersInfoW`.

Comment: The code you describe should work. Please show some more relevant code. Read what a [mcve] is and why it is useful to post one. Did you check the return value of `SystemParametersInfoW`? And if you did, did you check the value of `GetLastError`? Did you read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow?

Comment: What is `file.path`? Where does it point to? And why `char *buff` if `path` is a `wchar_t*`? Didn't you get a compiler warning?

Comment: You don't need to use char* at all. Use wchar_t* and wchar_t version of snprintf - [swprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question title is *use wchar_t *buff with variable*, but that's exactly what you did **not** do.

```
char *buff = "C:\\Users\\Prince 2 lu\\Desktop\\SDL\\bin\\image\\wallpaper.png";
SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, buff, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

This is wrong, because `buff` is a pointer to `char` but `SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,...` wants a pointer to `wchar_t`.

So either you use `SystemParametersInfoA` or you need this:

```
wchar_t *buff = L"C:\\Users\\Prince 2 lu\\Desktop\\SDL\\bin\\image\\wallpaper.png";
SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (void*)buff, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

Don't mix up `char` (normal 8 bit character) and `wchar_t` (wide 16 bit character).

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the path ""C:\\Users\\Prince 2 lu\\........." is only for test, my problem is to define buff in a variable (the path of the wallpaper for everyone) here you say L"string" but I want like L(my variable) you see?

Comment: `buff` must point to a wide char string. Maybe you should tell s what _exactly_ you're trying to achive. This answer answers your question, it explains why your code does not work and it provides a solution.

Comment: Can I use mbstowcs() for change the char string into a wide char string and define buff to a Var ?

Comment: @Prince2lu yes you can. But best would be to just use wide strings from the beginning.

Comment: If you don't want to use wide chars at all you can use `SystemParametersInfoA` (not the A instead of the W at the end), and with that you can use a `char*`.

Comment: *"The `(void*)` cast is needed"* - No, [it isn't](https://godbolt.org/z/84rKK4584).

Comment: @IInspectable you are right, answer edited